# DatePicker always displays when navigating from one page to another page in iOS Device

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova, datepicker

I'm working in `jQuery` with `Cordova` plugins to display `datepicker` based on device/browser(Below Code). In `iOS` Device, `DatePicker` always displays at bottom of application when navigating from one page to another page. But this code is working fine in desktop browser, Android device.

```
events: {
"click #datePicker": "selectDate"
},

selectDate: function () {
   var self = this;
   var datePicker = window.plugins.datePicker;
   if (window.plugins && window.plugins.datePicker) {
    datePicker.show({
        date: this.currentDate,
            mode: 'date', // date or time or blank for both
            allowOldDates: true
            }, function (returnDate) {
            var newDate = new Date(returnDate);
            self.updateCurrentDate(newDate);
        });
}
        else {
            $('#dpDatePicker').datebox('open');
        }
},
```

Let me know how to handle this issue?

Comment: may be in IOS window.plugins.datePicker getting undeifned.. have you try to debbug in IOS?

Comment: Thanks. window.plugins.datePicker is loading properly and datePicker is displaying. So I tried to close current picker and I am unable to to find whether it is opened or not.

As per code, if it is nothing datePicker will not open.